# Issue with Classes - Program works as intended, but visual studio code is highlighting syntax error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

My program is working as intended, it outputs the correct values when I perform a transfer from account 1 to account 2.

However, visual studio code is underlining "self" in red (e.g. telling me "Instance of 'Account' has no 'filepath' member)

Could you help me understand what I'm doing wrong? thanks so much!

Here is my code and output below, thanks so much!

```
class Account:
 
    def __init__(self):
        filepath=self.filepath  #self is underlined here
        with open(filepath,"r") as file:
            self.balance = int(file.read())
    
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount
    
    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
 
    def transfer(self, amount, receiver):
        self.newbalance = self.balance - amount
        receiver.newbalance = receiver.balance + amount
        print(self.accountname,"balance is",self.balance) #self is underlined here
        print(receiver.accountname,"balance is",receiver.balance)
        print(self.accountname,"transfering",amount,"to",receiver.accountname) #self is underlined here
        print(self.accountname, "new balance is",self.newbalance) #self is underlined here
        print(receiver.accountname, "new balance is",receiver.newbalance) 
 
class Louis(Account):
 
    accountname = "Louis" 
    filepath = "louis.txt"
 
class Romain(Account):
 
    accountname = "Romain"
    filepath = "romain.txt"
 
romain = Romain()
louis = Louis()
 
romain.transfer(99,louis)
```

Output

```
Romain balance is 2000
Louis balance is 1000
Romain transfering 99 to Louis
Romain new balance is 1901
Louis new balance is 1099
```

Comment: The syntax is fine. You are having a potential `AttributeError` if you try to create an `Account` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the inheritance is leading to some confusion here. While Louis and Roman both initialize `filepath`, the account base class never initializes `filepath`. Visual studio is flagging this a syntax error because if you had have initialized an instance of Account, your code would have raised an `AttributeError`. For instance:

```
class Account:    
     
    def __init__(self):    
        filepath=self.filepath  #self is underlined here    
        with open(filepath,"r") as file:    
            self.balance = int(file.read())    
        
    def withdraw(self, amount):    
        self.balance -= amount    
        
    def deposit(self, amount):    
        self.balance += amount    
     
    def transfer(self, amount, receiver):    
        self.newbalance = self.balance - amount    
        receiver.newbalance = receiver.balance + amount    
        print(self.accountname,"balance is",self.balance) #self is underlined here    
        print(receiver.accountname,"balance is",receiver.balance)    
        print(self.accountname,"transfering",amount,"to",receiver.accountname) #self is underlined here    
        print(self.accountname, "new balance is",self.newbalance) #self is underlined here    
        print(receiver.accountname, "new balance is",receiver.newbalance)     
     
class Louis(Account):    
     
    accountname = "Louis"     
    filepath = "louis.txt"    
     
class Romain(Account):    
     
    accountname = "Romain"    
    filepath = "romain.txt"    
     
romain = Romain()    
louis = Louis()    
     
romain.transfer(99,louis)    
    
account = Account()
```

Output

```
Romain balance is 2000
Louis balance is 1000
Romain transfering 99 to Louis
Romain new balance is 1901
Louis new balance is 1099
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test.py", line 38, in <module>
    account = Account()
  File "/home/test.py", line 4, in __init__
    filepath=self.filepath  #self is underlined here
AttributeError: 'Account' object has no attribute 'filepath'
```

Comment: ah I see! Thanks so much - how would I need to modify the code such that calling 'Account()' wouldn't lead to an error then?

Comment: I fixed it by adding filepath = "" and accountname ="" as variable under my class Account() but I don't find it very elegant -- is there a different way that i'm missing?

Comment: It's tough to answer because I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do. That being said I would avoid inheritance in this situation unless for some reason Louis/Romain need to have some functionality that shouldn't be provided by Account. Instead I would prefer louis and romain to be instances of an Account that takes `accountname` and `filepath` as parameters. So: `louis = Account("Louis", "louis.txt")`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only set `filepath` in the subclasses. If you try to create an `Account` object rather than a `Louis` or `Romain`, or you use another subclass that doesn't set `filepath`, you'll get an error. VS Code doesn't have any way of knowing that you never do this, it just analyzes the class by itself.

Comment: thanks so much! does it mean i'm ok with the code as is? or is there an elegant way of fixing that code such that it doesn't highlight this error?

Comment: I fixed it by adding filepath = "" and accountname ="" as variable under my class Account() but I don't find it very elegant -- is there a different way that i'm missing?

Comment: Maybe declare it as an abstract base class.\

Answer (score 0):

your `filepath` is a **Class** variable not an **Instance** variable

Louis and Romain need to be instances of an `Account`

```
class Account:    
     
    def __init__(self, accountname, filepath):
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.accountname = accountname
        self.balance = 0
        with open(self.filepath,"r") as file:    
            self.balance = int(file.read())    
        
    def withdraw(self, amount):    
        self.balance -= amount    
        
    def deposit(self, amount):    
        self.balance += amount    
     
    def transfer(self, amount, receiver):    
        self.newbalance = self.balance - amount    
        receiver.newbalance = receiver.balance + amount    
        print(self.accountname,"balance is",self.balance)
        print(receiver.accountname,"balance is",receiver.balance)    
        print(self.accountname,"transfering",amount,"to",receiver.accountname)
        print(self.accountname, "new balance is",self.newbalance)
        print(receiver.accountname, "new balance is",receiver.newbalance)     
    
romain = Account("Romain", "romain.txt")
louis = Account("Louis", "louis.txt")

romain.transfer(99,louis)
```